# php no detecta variable enviada metodo get con ajax

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, php7

Hola amigo mira ya modifique el index html, aca solamente modifique la ruta de open en el ajax para enviarla hacia el servidor.php, la cambie en la funcion mostrar y en la funcion actualizar tal cual como me explicaste.

```
    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="info"> </div>

        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var resultado= document.getElementById("info");

        function mostrarUsuarios(){

        var variable;
        variable= new XMLHttpRequest();
        variable.onreadystatechange= function(){
        if(variable.readyState===4 &&  variable.status===200){
        var respuesta= variable.responseText;
        resultado.innerHTML=respuesta;
        }
        }
        variable.open("GET","servidor.php?action=mostrar&personas="+"personas",true);
        variable.send();
        }
        // aca afuera ejecutamos la funcion mostrar usuarios
        mostrarUsuarios();

        function editarUsuario(id_cliente){
     var nombreid= "nombreId"+ id_cliente;
     var emailid="EmailId"+emailid;
     var borrar="borrar"+ id_cliente;
     var actualizar="actualizar"+ id_cliente;
     var editarnombreid=nombreid+"-editar";

     //aca vamos a obtener el nombre de cada persona
     var nombredeusuario= document.getElementById(nombreid).innerHTML;
      //vamos almacenarlo en una variable padre
     var parent= document.querySelector("#"+nombreid);
//esto quiere decir si al darle editar no tiene cajita osea null entonces creamos la cajita
     if(parent.querySelector("#"+editarnombreid)===null){
  //esto es para que me cree una cajita y yo al darle en editar en la cajita me deja editar los datos
   document.getElementById(nombreid).innerHTML='<input type="text" id="'+editarnombreid+'"value="'+nombredeusuario+'">';
   //aca inhabilitamos al boton borrar cuando le demos en editar
   document.getElementById(borrar).disabled="true";
//vamos a mostrar actualizar usuario este codigo habilita el boton
document.getElementById(actualizar).style.display="block";
     }


        }

 //actualizar

         function actualizarusuario(id_cliente){

            var variable;
            variable= new XMLHttpRequest();
            //aca recogemos el id de la cajita
          var nombreactualizado = document.getElementById("nombreId" + id_cliente + "-editar").value;
          variable.onreadystatechange=function(){

            if(variable.readyState==4 && variable.status==200){
                 mostrarUsuarios();
            }else{
                document.write("algo malo");
            }
          }
          variable.open("GET","servidor.php?action=editar&usuarioIDActualizado="+ usuarioID + "&nombreActualizado="+ nombreActualizado,true);
          variable.send();
         }




        function borrarusuario(id_cliente){
//aca consultamos si esta seguro de borrarlo y si es si se almacena en respuesta y se hace el comparador y si es no pues no hara nada
    var respuesta=confirm("estas seguro de borrra este usuario?");

    if(respuesta===true){
        var variable;
        variable= new XMLHttpRequest();
        variable.onreadystatechange= function(){
        if(variable.readyState===4 &&  variable.status===200){
                 mostrarUsuarios();

                }
        }
        variable.open("GET","servidor.php??usuarioideliminado="+id_cliente,true);
        variable.send();
        }
        }
        </script>


    </body>
```

y en esta parte si modifique la mayor parte del codigo del servidor.php como me lo explicaste y utilice la estructura switch para hacerlo como se envia desde el index, con la funcion que realizara en el switch, pero aun me sale el notice que me explicaste no se si tengo mal acomodado el codigo quedo atento a tus comentarios este es el servidor.php con lo que me explicaste ya me actualiza el dato en la bd, pero sigue saliendo el notice de las variables indefinidas, pero si esta actualizando la bd

```
  <?php
include_once "metodo.php";

//creamos las variables de tipo cadena que son as que mostrare en tabla

$nombreId       = "nombreId";
$emailId        = "emailId";
$actualizar     = "actualizar";
$borrar         = "borrar";
$mostrarUsarios = new Mostrador();
$mAction        = !empty($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : null;

/*Si la clave action existe ...*/
if ($mAction) {

    /*Trabajaremos con switch, pero puedes hacerlo de otro modo*/
    switch ($mAction) {
        case "mostrar":

            if ($personas === "personas") {
                $datos    = $mostrarUsarios->mostrar();
                $personas = $_GET['personas'];
                ?>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>nombre</th>
      <th>correo</th>
      <th>actualizar</th>
      <th>borrar</th>
    </tr>

    <?php
foreach ($datos as $dato) {
                    ?>
        <tr>
        <?php
//aca simplemente se hace comoyo hago solo que se llamo a esas variables para que diga el texto y el id asi correio8  simplemente para no mander el id  solo
                    ?>
          <td id="<?php echo $nombreId . $dato['id_cliente'] ?>"><?php echo $dato['nombre_cliente']; ?></td>
          <td id="<?php echo $emailId . $dato['id_cliente'] ?>"><?php echo $dato['email_cliente']; ?></td>
          <?php
// aca le damos un id a cada boton y es el id del usuario
                    ?>
        <?php
//luego aca metemos la funcion editar usuaria que la tenemos en el index ?>
          <td><input id="<?php echo $dato['id_cliente'] ?>" type="button" onclick="editarUsuario(this.id)" value="editar"></td>
          <td><input onclick="borrarusuario(<?php echo $dato['id_cliente']; ?>)" id="<?php echo $borrar . $dato['id_cliente'] ?>" type="button" value="borrar"></td>
          <?php // a este le ponemos un estilo oculto por que solo va aparecer si presiono actualizar

                    //y luego le damos la funcionalidad de actualizar al boton y en la funcion meti codigo php con el id del cliente
                    ?>
          <td><input onclick="actualizarusuario(<?php echo $dato['id_cliente']; ?>);" id="<?php echo $actualizar . $dato['id_cliente'] ?>" type="button" value="actualizar" style="display: none;"></td>


        </tr>
        <?php
}
                ?>
       </table>
<?php
}

            ?>
<?php
break;

        case "editar":

            $usuarioidactualizado = $_GET["usuarioidactualizado"];

            $nombreactualizado = $_GET["nombreactualizado "];

            $datos  = new Mostrador();
            $datosd = new Mostrador();
            if (!empty($nombreactualizado)) {
                $con       = $this->bd;
                $cliente   = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $nombreactualizado);
                $resultado = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE clientes SET nombre_cliente='$cliente' WHERE id_usuario=$usuaridactualizado");
            }

            $eliminador = new Mostrador();
            if (!empty($usuarioideliminado)) {

            }
            ?>
  <?php

            break;

        default:
            /*
            Aquí haces una operación por defecto cuando haya otro
            tipo de action o muestras un mensaje
             */
            break;
    }
} else {
    /*Esto lo puedes cambiar por otra cosa, como un array con una clave error*/
    echo "No se posteó una clave action";
}

?>
```

Comment: Cómo sabes que sí las estás enviando? Ya revisaste tu pestaña de red? Aparecen esas variables en la URL en logs de servidor? Y porqué editas con get? No te preocupa hacer demasiado fácil que te inyecten SQL?

Comment: Según esto: `variable.open("GET","servidor.php?personas="+"personas",true)` estarías enviando únicamente un dato bajo la clave `personas`. Ten en cuenta que, partiendo de `?` la URL es serializada en `$_GET` que no es otra cosa que un array cuyas claves son los valores de la izquierda y el dato correspondiente a esa clave es el valor de la derecha. Revisa en la documentación como funciona GET y como se organizan los valores que pasas vía Ajax.

Comment: Hola amigos, estoy realizando esto viendo de un vídeo de youtube creo que lo está enviando por que ya está en el open enviando, y según la segunda respuesta, personas está bien y funciona, tengo el problema es con el de actualizar , esa son las variables que no está reconociendo, quedo atento amigos a sus comentarios mil gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si observas bien, el código de `servidor.php` no está diferenciado. Es decir, estás enviando peticiones Ajax a ese archivo **en dos contextos distintos** sin diferenciar nada en la recepción. De modo que cuando mandas la petición relativa a `personas`, el código intentará cosas como esta: `$_GET['usuarioIDActualizado'];`, pero en ese caso la petición no tiene una clave `usuarioIDActualizado` y en consecuencia saltará el `Notice`.

Esto lo puedes resolver agregando una clave en la petición que te permita decidir en el servidor lo que hay que hacer con esa petición y qué datos hay que obtener.

Dado que el código es largo, te pondré solamente dos ejemplos de petición donde agregaremos una clave `action` en base a la cual decidiremos en el servidor qué valores habrá que buscar y qué operaciones habrá que ejecutar.

### Javascript / Ajax

```
    function mostrarUsuarios(){
        // ... código
        //Petición con una clave action=mostrar
        variable.open("GET","servidor.php?action=mostrar&personas="+"personas",true);
        // ... código
    }


    function editarUsuarios(){
        // ... código
        //Petición con una clave action=editar
         variable.open("GET","servidor.php?action=editar&usuarioIDActualizado="+ usuarioID + "&nombreActualizado="+ nombreActualizado,true);
        // ... código
    }
```

### PHP

```
/*
   Primero verificamos el action
*/
$mAction=!empty($_GET["action"]) ? $_GET["action"] : NULL;

/*Si la clave action existe ...*/
if ($mAction) {

    /*Trabajaremos con switch, pero puedes hacerlo de otro modo*/
    switch ($mAction) {
        case "mostrar":
            /*
               Aquí haces las operaciones relativas a mostrar
               como obtener $_GET["persona"]  y otras
            */
            break;
    
        case "editar":
            /*
               Aquí haces las operaciones relativas a editar
               como obtener $_GET["usuarioIDActualizado"]  y otras
            */
            break;
    
        default:
            /*
               Aquí haces una operación por defecto cuando haya otro
               tipo de action o muestras un mensaje  
            */
           break;
    }
} else {
    /*Esto lo puedes cambiar por otra cosa, como un array con una clave error*/
    echo "No se posteó una clave action";
}
```

Si analizas el código, verás que estamos ante un programa controlado y coherente con las peticiones que se recibirán desde el cliente. Debido a la clave `action` que pusimos en Ajax sabremos en el servidor qué datos vendrán con esa petición. De ese modo, no se intentará buscar la clave `usuarioIDActualizado` en un contexto en el cual dicha clave no fue enviada.

Espero te sirva. Si hay algún problema o duda dilo en comentarios a esta respuesta para ser notificado.

Comment: Hola amigo A.decano, creo que hice lo que me dijiste pero no me funciona quizas tu explicacion este perfecta, yo soy nuevo en esto, quizas no se como acomodar el codigo, lo realice como entendi pero no me funciona, como podria hacer para compartirte mi codigo?

Comment: @Camilo34 puedes editar la pregunta poniendo al final la nueva versión del código para revisarla.

Comment: acabe de modificarla , quedo atento

Comment: @Camilo34 no veo que hayas aplicado en tu código el cambio indicado en mi respuesta. **Tienes que agregar el código en tú pregunta**, no en mi respuesta.

Comment: que pena con tigo,  creo que ya acabe de modificar la pregunta en mi codigo  sigo atento a tus consejos

Comment: @Camilo34 he visto el código editado. ¿Qué comportamiento tiene ahora? ¿Sigue mostrando el Notice, da error, muestra algo, qué muestra, no muestra nada?

Comment: Hola, mira ya puedo actualizar, pero me sigue saliendo el notice, pero al parecer si lo reconoce, por que actualiza, que sera?

Comment: @Camilo34 En los GET tienes que poner los nombres de cada clave exactamente igual que como los pusiste en Ajax. Por ejemplo, estás poniendo esto: `$_GET["usuarioidactualizado"]` pero en Ajax el dato es pasado con la clave `usuarioIDActualizado`. Tienes que respetar la norma *case sensitive*, o sea, respetar las mayúsculas/minúsculas. Debes igualar la forma en que lees los datos en el servidor, poniendo por ejemplo: `$_GET["usuarioIDActualizado"]`

Comment: perfecto, ahoa si me fuciono a la perfeccion , ya teagradezco con la mejor respuesta en el sistema,  y en la realidad te agradezco  infinitamente mil y mil gracias  ya podre continuar con el curso estaba estacado hace dias, mil gracias por compartir tu conocimiento